# Can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component after adding await tag to dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have added an await tag to a redux dispatch and now I receive this error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in LoginForm (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at login.js:12)
    in div (at login.js:11)
```

Can someone please explain why this is occurring and how I can go about 'cleaning up'my asynchronous task? I don't understand which component has not been mounted

My code:

login.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginForm from '../components/form/loginForm';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { SUCCESS, HOME } from '../common/webUtils';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    if( this.props.loginStatus === SUCCESS ) return <Redirect to = {HOME}/>
    else return (
      <div style = {{paddingTop: "180px", background: 'radial-gradient(circle, rgba(106,103,103,1) 0%, rgba(36,36,36,1) 100%)', height: "100vh"}}>
        <LoginForm/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps( state ) {
  return {
    loginStatus: state.userReducer.loginStatus
  }
}

export default connect ( mapStateToProps ) ( Login );
```

Dispatch code that causes the warning from loginForm.js:

```
async function handleSubmit() {
    setSubmitted( true )
    if( isValidForm() ) {
      const details = {
          "username": userName,
          "password": password
      }
      await props.login( details )
      if( props.loginStatus !== SUCCESS ) handleShowError()
    } else { 
      handleShowError()
    }
  }
```

setShowError function and corresponding state value initialisation:

```
const [showError, setShowError] = React.useState( false )

const handleShowError = () => {
    setShowError( true )
  };
```

Comment: What does handleShowError do exactly? Share the code for that.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky added it, it sets boolean state value

Comment: You are setting state from redux actions?

Comment: I don't think so? the action i dispatch is at props.login which should update the loginStatus value in my store. Then based on the loginStatus value I execute the handleShowError() function which is located in loginForm.js @AlexanderStaroselsky

Comment: Look at your title. You cannot update the state of an unmounted component.

Comment: It looks like you executing useState setter operations. Usually with redux you would instead dispatch other actions that would update store state via the reducer. If you remove handleShowError do you get the same error? It’s hard to see everything without knowing the actions, reducers, etc

Comment: so if i remove handleShowError after the await props.login( details) theres no error.

Comment: Thank you for the insight @PabloDarde but i dont understand how this component isn't mounted when it is being rendered. And the error only occurs when i add an await tag to my dispatch so why would that cause my component to be unmounted

Comment: Try instead remove anything from redux actions/reducers that executes setState. Instead dispatch additional actions that update something like the error state via the reducer. Try that then update your question if you continue having errors. Disregard hooks for a moment, and just update store state via actions and reducers, mapping/connecting that state to props in your component.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the login is not get notified by "async function handleSubmit" result
I  believe this the reason the component is not get mounted.

In general, with redux, you need middleware such thunk or saga to manage the service workers in the background.

Redux alone cannot do this job.